# Displaying files from Bundle into UITableView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, resources, nsbundle

I have got few audio files in my bundle, and I want to display them (names) in a `UITableView`. And when user taps on any `cell`, the audio file with that name should play.

e.g.
[image]

I googled but all I got was to read files from Documents Directory.

How can I display my bundle files?

Please help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to get first a pointer to your main bundle, in which the resources of the app are stored. Using this pointer, you can search for all resources with extension mp3.
You can use code like:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSArray *paths = [mainBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil];
```

The last element in every path is the file name of the respective mp3 file.

For more information, please look up Apple's [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the **tableview didselectrowatindexpath** method  write this code

```
NSString * soundSelected = cell.textlabel.text;
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],soundSelected];
        NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        AVAudioPlayer* cellTapSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
        [cellTapSound play];
```